# checking the value and changing the text of many radio buttons on an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with many radio buttons. Can I check if **any** one of these radio buttons is checked ? and then change the text of that checked radio button ?

I'm using asp.net c# 3.5

I'm using

```
RadioButton ff = new RadioButton();
RadioButton ff2 = new RadioButton();
RadioButton ff3 = new RadioButton();
RadioButton ff4 = new RadioButton();
```

in a for loop to create many radio buttons

Comment: need aspx page you have written to explain it in detail. what checkbox you have used server control or simple html?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using an asp:RadioButton, then one method is to set the AutoPostBack property of the RadioButton to true.

Then in a handler on the server side you can change the text.

Evidently this has a cost.

e.g.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="ctrlRadioButton" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    oncheckedchanged="ctrlRadioButton_CheckedChanged" Text="Select this" />
```

Then in your code class

```
protected void ctrlRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrlRadioButton.Text = "New Text";
}
```

**Update:**

If you create the RadioButtons dynamically:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton() { AutoPostBack = true, Text = "Initial text" };
        rb.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
        Form.Controls.Add(rb); // Or add to a panel if you prefer
    }
}
```

and the handler is

```
protected void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    rb.Text = "New Text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run loop on all the radio button on your page by using **jquery** on `type="radio"`
and find checked radio button and change text of that radio button.

Try this code:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')) { $(this).html("yourname") }
});
```